# TLS encryption with a self-signed PKI and Python’s asyncio module

Tags: tls, pki

I want to enable TLS encryption with a custom / self-signed PKI for
a self-contained distributed system built with Python 3’s asyncio.

I’ve read Python’s [ssl docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) as 
well as several tutorials:

- http://www.area536.com/projects/be-your-own-certificate-authority-with-openssl/
- http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/
- http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2013/1/24/python-ssl-socket-echo-test-with-self-signed-certificate
- https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-build-your-own-public-key-infrastructure/
- http://blog.gosquadron.com/use-tls

From all this, I extracted the following steps in order to create a minimal
example for a simple client and server with a self-signed PKI.

It *seems* to work as expected, but I’m unsure if I missed anything or create
non-obvious bugs which could reduce or nullify the security of the system.

Here is what I did so far:

I'll create one root CA which signs a CSR for each machine.  Each machine will
have its own certificate and key.

Considerations for the root CA:

- The key length should be 2048 bits, or better, 4096 bits.
- A strong passphrase should be used.
- The key should not leave the machine (except if you store it on an SD card
  and hide it somewhere save).  Level of paranoia should depend on the security
  needs.
- The certificate should not use the same FQDN as any production system.

Generate the key and a self-signed certificate:

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key 4096
$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -key ca.key -out ca.pem -days 1000
```

Create a key and a certificate signing request (CSR) on a machine:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096
$ openssl genrsa -out client.key 4096
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
$ openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
```

Now you can sign the device key with your CA cert:

```
$ openssl x509 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -req -in server.csr -out server.pem -days 365
$ openssl x509 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -req -in client.csr -out client.pem -days 365
```

Minimal Python example.  We need different SSLContexts for the client and
server, because they do some things differently.  Both, client and server, will
use TLS 1.2 with ECDH-AESGCM.  They will verify each other’s certificates
against the root CA cert.  The client also checks the server’s host name.  ECDH
keys are only used once per SSL session and compression is disabled:

```
import asyncio
import ssl


@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_client(reader, writer):
    data = yield from reader.read(100)
    print(data)
    writer.write(b'cya')
    yield from writer.drain()
    writer.close()


@asyncio.coroutine
def client(addr, ssl_ctx):
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(*addr, ssl=ssl_ctx)
    writer.write(b'ohai')
    data = yield from reader.read(100)
    print(data)
    writer.close()


addr = ('127.0.0.1', 5555)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Setup server
server_ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
server_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
server_ctx.options |= ssl.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
server_ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION
server_ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='server.pem', keyfile='server.key')
server_ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='ca.pem')
server_ctx.set_ciphers('ECDH+AESGCM')

coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_client, *addr, ssl=server_ctx)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Run client
client_ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
client_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
client_ctx.check_hostname = True
client_ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='client.pem', keyfile='client.key')
client_ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='ca.pem')
client_ctx.set_ciphers('ECDH+AESGCM')

loop.run_until_complete(client(addr, client_ctx))

# Shutdown
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

The script will output

```
b'ohai'
b'cya'
```

as expected and TLS *seems* to work.  Are there any problems with it or things
that could be done better?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll re-post it there. I was not aware of this community and thought crypto would fit.

Comment: Code Review seems to be the wrong place, too.  Since the main focus of my question is SSL certificates and parameters, this might indeed be the right community. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95143/tls-encryption-with-a-self-signed-pki-and-python-s-asyncio-module?noredirect=1#comment173686_95143

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misleading pointer in case CR was wrong. However, questions with code generally get closed here.

Comment: My question is more about the parameter values for the SSLContext and the PKI creation processs and less about the code (especially that of the server and client) itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I stumbled on this checking something else, a few minor points

- A CA doesn't sign a CSR; it signs (issues) a cert that has some important data taken from the CSR but much data different.
- The *Subject* names of the CA cert and all server and client certs it issues should be unique, and preferably mnemonic. The CA and client names don't need to be FQDNs, or domainnames at all, although if they are FQDNs that helps make them unique, and usually mnemonic. For a server, either the CommonName *part* of the Subject or the SubjectAlternativeName extension if used *should* -- and for many but not all clients *must* -- match the 'hostname' used by the client(s) to connect to the server. Normally this is the FQDN, but in test and intranet settings it might not; your example shows connecting to the loopback or 'localhost' *address* 127.0.0.1.
- ECDH-AESGCM is not a ciphersuite or even a keyexchange in SSL/TLS; ECDH+AESGM is an OpenSSL shorthand for 8 different cipher suites -- only 2 of which work with an RSA key+cert, namely ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 and ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256.
- You don't visibly specify the temporary (ephemeral) ecdh parameters (curve) so you are presumably getting a default from Python; OpenSSL itself doesn't have a default, although 1.0.2 up has a nondefault option to automatically use the client preference.
  Since you've chosen everything else pretty strong, you should make sure the ECDHE curve isn't unacceptably weak. I would hope it can be found in the Python source; if not, monitor an actual connection with Wireshark or similar to check.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for confirmation that the context has logical values being set, then I could say it does.  Can't say I know anything about doing this in python though.